# 3 tier Architecture using EF5 with Database-first approch in MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-database-first, 3-tier

I am new to MVC and EF.
I use to follow 3 tier architecture before with asp.net with BO,BLL,DAL,UI(asp.net webform).

I want to follow same with MVC4 in UI layer, in replace of webform.

I have generated my entity from database in DAL but now I am confused what is the use of BO layer now ?
Because all my entity are in DAL layer itself.

Also I will create Viewmodel classes in model folder so don't know how the flow will go now.

I am confused about the architecture now, please suggest if I am doing it correct or not, or is there any different approach  I have to take for best practice,

PS: I don't wanna use single layer in my project. I think EF save our time by creating BO classes and enable sp used as functions and we don't have to use Ado.net repetitive code again and again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why EF5 when EF6 came out last year?

Comment: it's a typo, it is EF 4  i am using @Dai

Comment: Okay then, why are you using EF4 when EF6 came out last year?

Comment: i can't use higher versions it is only available to me ... EF6 what special will it do in my case ...?? @Dai

Comment: still no luck , please suggest @Dai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As finally no help I got from 29 views counts, So I opted to create BO again from my project, DAL consist of E.F and UI have Viewmodels and ViewmodalList.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, DAL should .edmx files. And if you want to use repository patterns you can add there. 
In Business Logic layer, you will add your services. Where you are actually performing database operations. 
You can declare another layer for interfaces as well. Or you can use Business logic layer for it.